# Memory issue exporting many JSON records to CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, out-of-memory, export-to-csv

I am using the code below to export nearly 3,000 JSON records to CSV format. It is working in Chrome and Opera but not in Safari, IE, or Firefox. I have an "out of browser memory" issue.

Why doesn't it work in those browsers?
How can I export many (e.g. 90,000) records in any browser?

```
function exportAll(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {

  var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;    
  var CSV = '';

  CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

  if (ShowLabel) {

    var row = "";

    for (var index in arrData[0]) {    
      row += index + ',';
    }

    row = row.slice(0, -1);    
    CSV += row + '\r\n';

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {

    var row = "";

    for (var index in arrData[i]) {
      row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
    }

    row.slice(0, row.length - 1);    
    CSV += row + '\r\n';

  }

  if (CSV == '') {
    alert("Invalid data");
    return;
  }    

  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.id = "lnkDwnldLnk";

  //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
  document.body.appendChild(link);

  var csv = CSV;
  blob = new Blob([csv], {
    type: 'text/csv'
  });

  var csvUrl = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var filename = 'GraphsData.csv';

  $("#lnkDwnldLnk")
    .attr({
      'download': filename,
      'href': csvUrl
    });

  $('#lnkDwnldLnk')[0].click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);

}
```

Comment: how much data in each record, how did you get from nearly 3000 at the beginning of the question to more than 90000 by the time the question was finished?

Comment: window.webkitURL only exists in chrome and opera, this is why it doesn't work in firefox or Internet Exploder

Comment: I have asked two questions one at the top and other at the bottom

Comment: Yes, you export 90000 records the same way you export 3000, it's just 30 times bigger (?)

Comment: Where do you get these 90.000 JSON "Records" from? From a server application? Why not generating the csv over there w/o any mem issues on the client? Besides memory, how long do you think this will take on a client until the "timeout" box appears?